# Plotting some data in a weird format in excel/python

Tags: python, excel

I have some data that is in this format:

| Position | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | A |
| 2 | C | A | C |
| 3 | B | D | E |

Is there a way to plot this data? The way it is set up is that the table is sorta like a line chart, I know its weird but that's the way the data came out as.

If not excel, then maybe in python?

I don't know how to plot this data. It is already in a kind of format as if it is a graph though, the cells are like a point of data on a line graph.

Comment: can you describe the type of plot you want to achieve?

Comment: "the table is sorta like a line chart" In hat way? What is your expected output? What is the independent and dependent variable you want to plot? What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)?

Comment: im trying to create a line graph, like in the above example A would be at 1 in 2012, 2 in 2013 and 1 at 2014.

Comment: I don't think the line plot is a good representation especially with sparse data. For example, C does not appear because it's not possible to draw a line between 2012 and 2014. However you can front fill values to get a dense matrix. It depends on the meaning you want to give to your data. (See my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` and `matplotlib` to pivot your dataframe and plot your figure:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# Read your data
# df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
data = {'Position': [1, 2, 3],
        '2012': ['A', 'C', 'B'],
        '2013': ['B', 'A', 'D'],
        '2014': ['A', 'C', 'E']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Reshape your table
piv = (df.melt('Position', var_name='Year', value_name='ID')
         .pivot(index='Year', columns='ID', values='Position'))

# Plot data
ax = piv.plot(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Position', title='Rank by year')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator())
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Pivoted dataframe:

```
>>> piv
ID      A    B    C    D    E
Year                         
2012  1.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
2013  2.0  1.0  NaN  3.0  NaN
2014  1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  3.0
```

Note: you probably do the same with Excel.

Comment: Yes this is what I was thinking, I was having trouble finding a way to pivot the table like that in excel. Might just have to do it in python then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there appear to be no *values* to plot so you're probably limited to plotting the *order* (position) of things.

For example, the plot information for 2012 would simply specify the order `A, C, B` with no value comparisons.

However, you already *have* that level of information in the 2012 column so I'm not sure what a graphical plot would add.

You *definitely* don't need a plot for showing position 1 in each year (as per one of your comments) since that information is easily discernible just by looking at the single row of the table. Graphs are meant to make data more obvious rather than just provide a pretty picture, despite the proclivities of the management consultant hordes :-)

---

If you *did* want to show relevant positions, two possibilities would be as follows, assigning a "fake" value to each, calculated as something like `4 - position` which would translate positions `{1, 2, 3}` into values `{3, 2, 1}`, hence giving a higher value to the first position.

First, a series of pie charts, one per year, showing the items based on those fake values. This would give you something like (apologies for the crude rendering, I whipped it up quickly in Word):

[image]

Second, you could present it as a categorised bar chart, similar to (need to add the data for 2013 and other years):

[image]